# How do you define an enum that can only be created by its companion object? (think smart constructors)

Tags: scala, scala-3

I've tried making the constructor private, like this:

```scala
enum X {
  case Stuff private (value: Int)
}

object X {
  def stuff(s: String) = 
    X.Stuff(performSomeValidationAndCalculation(s))
}
```

but it complains:

```
method apply cannot be accessed as a member of Playground.X.Stuff.type from module class X$
```

I would like to force callers to use the smart constructor to prevent an invalid enum from being instantiated and to limit the number of introduction forms.

Comment: Could you say more about what problem this is meant to solve? The general assumption with enums/ADTs is that they are "dumb" record types that encode variants; for that reason, the data constructors are assumed to have the same privacy as the type itself.

Comment: edited to clarify intent: I would like to force callers to use the smart constructor to prevent an invalid enum from being instantiated and to limit the number of introduction forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the class name to private to limit the scope:

```
enum X {
  case Stuff private[X] (value: Int)
}

object X {
  def stuff(s: String) = 
    X.Stuff(s.toInt)
}
```

Sample working code: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/hUPECAJFSzqAus6c5slBHQ